# Boolean Modifier issue with IcoSphere on specific positions

Tags: modifiers

I noticed a strange thing with boolean operations. I suppose it's a bug. Blender 2.90.1

Example 1:
With default cube still present:

- Create UVsphere. radius=0.5m at y=-1m z=1m.
- Subtract it from Cube (Shift-Click Cube, Ctrl Minus).

  => Works as expected
- Create IcoSphere. radius=0.5m at **y=1m** z=1m.
- Subtract it from Cube (Shift-Click Cube, Ctrl Minus).

  => Does a Union !!!???
- Change Difference to Union

  => Does a difference between the two, but only has the faces from the cube.... !!??
- Change it to Intersect

  => Leaves us with the IcoSphere alone !!??

Example 2:

Again from the default scene again with default Cube.

- Create IcoSphere. radius=0.5m at **y=-1m** z=1m.
- Subtract it from Cube (Shift-Click Cube, Ctrl Minus).

  => Does a difference between the two, but only has the faces from the cube. !?
- Change Difference to Union

  => Does Union fine.
- Change it to Intersect

  => Does Intersect, but result only has the cube faces. !?

Putting the IcoSphere back at y=1m does the same problem as Example 1.

Putting the IcoSphere in other places, and the operation works fine.

Comment: Please note that the issue happens whenever the icoSphere's center is exactly on one of the edges of the cube (including where edges intersect)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I thought that blender 2.90 already had the latest bool tool update, however it turns out this is not the case, this works fine in 2.91.